# Dell XPS 13 9350 WiFi does not work

Tags: wifi

I'm absolutely newbie in Linux world, and wanted to try it. By looking distros in the internet, came to Elementary OS which is I liked very much due its clean design.

So, downloaded it (0.4.1), burned on USB stick, and installed.
Everything is fine, except that there is no Wi-Fi (and no Ethernet too).
Trying to googling it a bit, looks like this issue with my laptop (or specifically - BCM4350) is pretty common. Anyway, wasting almost 4 hours on it - I didn't fix it.

Then started looking for other distros, and downloaded Linux Mint Mate 18.1. Even didn't yet installed it (because it loaded into try-it mode immediately) - and woohoo - WiFi works just fine out of the box.

There are some screenshots that I made in Mint, maybe they will help you to solve it in a future Elementary update (if it works fine in Mint, why it can't work in Elementary?):
https://puu.sh/w48z2/c7239d7cfe.jpg

https://puu.sh/w48zy/dc20effede.png

P.S. Main difference I noticed, is in Elementary it was: "kernel modules: brcmfmac, wl", when in Mint its just "brcmfmac".

Comment: P.P.S. No problem with Ubuntu 17.04 - wifi works out of the box:
https://puu.sh/w49or/ac2575a146.png
https://puu.sh/w49pb/e1c7c361ba.png

Comment: P.P.P.S. And screenshots of same commands for Elementary:
https://puu.sh/w49KY/c3b0a21c92.png

https://puu.sh/w49LC/434b3b43be.png

Comment: Weird. Are tryin to connect to 5ghz or 2.4? I have Dell XPS 9560 and it works just fine. not sure it's the same card though

Comment: I'm not trying connect to any network - because there is just no wifi/ethernet in Network center at all. Only "VPN" and "Proxy".
But my hotspot has both 2.4 and 5ghz network, if it matters.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source`

Answer (score 0):

This is the screenshot from my network settings. Are you saying that you don't have the section of wireless and Ethernet[image]?

Comment: Exactly. Only "VPN" and "Proxy". By the way, tried today also Zorin OS distro -- exactly the same problem. Vanilla Ubuntu 17.04 & Mint 18.1 wifi works fine out of the box, in case of Elementary & Zorin -- no ethernet/wifi at all.

Comment: can you see if there are exceptions in the lot related to this?